# Native Foreign Exchange Trading Software

Tags: software-recommendation

Know anyone any foreign exchange (forex) trading software native for OS X? (Not Windows emulated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](http://forextradingsoftwareformacusers.com/), it seems that your best choice may be some cross-platform Java app. [Another site](http://www.forexmac.com/) has reviews of other products.

Everything I've seen from those sites and others in [this Google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=forex+software+mac&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) reeks of marketing and astroturf, so it may behoove you to be wary.